# apache http rewrite/redirect based on ip

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I want to redirect an ip to another view of my website, for example, I want the visitor from ip x to see
www.xxx.com?_DEBUG=1
while all other visitors see the normal www.xxx.com,
how would I do this in apache config file, what directives are used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of a rewrite configuration to do what you want - put this inside the virtual host for www.xxx.com on your server:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} 1.2.3.4
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !_DEBUG=1
#RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /$1?_DEBUG=1 [QSA,R,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /$1?_DEBUG=1 [QSA,L]
```

A couple of notes:

- Change `1.2.3.4` to whatever IP you need
- The second `RewriteCond` prevents URLs already re-written to include `_DEBUG=1` from being re-written again
- There are two versions of the actual `RewriteRule`; the first version (commented out) actually performs a redirect.  Use this if you actually want the HTTP client to submit a second request to the server including the `_DEBUG=1` argument.  The downside is that if you're combining GET and POST data, this method will not work.
- The second version of the `RewriteRule` is what I recommend you use...it doesn't perform a redirect.  Instead it just appends the `_DEBUG=1` parameter to the HTTP request internally in Apache before the request is handled.

Comment: how would I do it for multiple ips(and ranges of ips?)

Comment: @user678070 `1.2.3.4` can be a pattern (e.g. 1.2.3.*).

Comment: this doesn't work for me, the url didn't get rewrite, does it work for you?