# .htacces redirect all visitor that are not from certain IP address multiple IP's

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do a redirect but for some reason I am getting an apache error page using the code below

```
# -> Rewrite START
Options ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 403 http://example.com

### Deny website access to users outsdie our IP addresses
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from xx.xx.xx.xx
allow from xx.xx.xx.xx
### Deny end
```

EDITED

Could someone please point me in the right direction. I'm new to .htaccess. How would i add another IP address to the code below?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=xx.xx.xx.xx
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com [L,R=301]
```

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025116/apache-http-rewrite-redirect-based-on-ip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025116/apache-http-rewrite-redirect-based-on-ip), [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911289/redirect-users-based-on-ip-address-apache-htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911289/redirect-users-based-on-ip-address-apache-htaccess)

Comment: @SquareCat Thanks, but This would not be suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting errors because of looping since request to your 403 will also cause 403 (since IPs will still match).

Try this code instead:

```
Options ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks

ErrorDocument 403 /

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(xx\.yy\.zz\.mm|aa\.bb\.cc\.dd)$
RewriteRule ^.+$ - [F]
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to work. I've edited my answer with your solution and it works. Could you please suggest how i would apply 2 different IP's to my example code? thanks

Comment: If you see my answer I have already provided you an example to provdide 2 or more IPs in the condition.

Comment: Let me know if you run into any problems with this.